# Laravel API: How to get data from foreign key from different table

Tags: laravel

I currently want to make an API that will get all the lessons by its module_id. These are currently my codes:

**Module Migration Table:**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateModulesTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('modules', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('module_name');            
            $table->bigInteger('created_by')->unsigned()->nullable(); 
            $table->bigInteger('updated_by')->unsigned()->nullable(); 

            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('modules', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('admins');
            $table->foreign('updated_by')->references('id')->on('admins');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('modules');
    }
}
```

**Lesson Migration Table**:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateLessonTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('lesson', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->bigInteger('module_id')->unsigned();
            $table->longText('content');
            $table->bigInteger('created_by')->unsigned()->nullable(); 
            $table->bigInteger('updated_by')->unsigned()->nullable(); 
            $table->string('enabled')->nullable(); 
            $table->string('position')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('lesson', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('module_id')->references('id')->on('modules');
            $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('admins');
            $table->foreign('updated_by')->references('id')->on('admins');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('lesson');
    }
}
```

And this is the **GetLessonByModule controller** of that API I want to make (getting all the lessons by its module_id):

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Lesson;
use App\Models\Modules;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class GetLessonByModuleController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $lessons = Lesson::all();
        return response($lessons,200);
    }
}
```

The module_id and the ID in the modules table are currently connected as seen in the migration tables. I just don't know how to compose it in my Controller. I also don't know if I should make a new model. Any kind of help/suggestion is deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As said vaska gamdelidze make sure that you had relation into Lesson module, after that change your code to: `$lessons = Lesson::query()->with('modules')->get();`

Comment: Watch out, this will create big query, fetching all Lessons with all their Modules. Besides that, it will not fulfill original requirement of "get all the lessons by its module_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Lesson;
use App\Models\Modules;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class GetLessonByModuleController extends Controller {
    public function index(int $module_id) {
        $lessons = Lesson::where('module_id', '=', $module_id)->get();
        return response($lessons,200);
    }
}
```

In your api.php there should be definition of the route:

```
Route::get('lessons-by-module/{module_id}', [\App\Http\Controllers::class, 'index']);
```

If it works for you and want to do it better, you can go fancy with Laravel routing explicit binding: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#explicit-binding

Comment: I'm sorry, what comes after the ->

Comment: Sorry for that, changed the original answer :) Method `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::get` will give a Collection of results.

Comment: This error popped up on postman = Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Api\GetLessonByModuleController] does not exist.

Comment: And I have double--triple checked it already, the routes are fine, I don't know why it's creating that error

Comment: Its about a namespace, definition you posted in the original question is `App\Http\Controllers\GetLessonByModuleController` while error visible via postman is about  `App\Http\Controllers\Api\GetLessonByModuleController`. See that extra `Api`?